# Auto-Starting Headless Chromium inside Docker

Tags: docker, chromium, headless

I am trying to start a headless chromium instance within an ubuntu docker image.
When I type the full docker launch line with the entry point in CLI and run it, it behaves as expected.

**However when I try to launch it with a systemd service on boot chromium is opened but the webpage isn't**
The dependencies for the systemd service to start requires an internet connection and system time to be correct. Don't know the difference between starting by hand versus with a shell script.

Here is the EntryPoint to the docker container

```
chromium-browser --no-sandbox --headless --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --no-first-run --disable-gpu --use-fake-ui-for-media-stream --disable-sync --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-audio-output https://......................
```